# Java ClassLoader to deal with "Instance" classes

Tags: java, security, log4j, classloader

As we know java class loading works like in picture below.

[image]

When we have a notion of plugin in our application (like app servers) we sometimes need some classes to be loaded in the instances class loader rather than in parent, so that each new instance (plugin, webapp or whatever) loads that particular class not delegating the parent...

For example Log4j classes, we need them to be loaded for *each* instance.

So in order to do this the best approach that came into my mind is to write custom classloader that will take a list of class names which shall be prevented from being delegated to parent classloader (ideally we want instances to be in complete isolation).

So the the application that will load other "instances" will use that custom classloader while loading those "instances"...

**Is there an implementation of such classloader that solves this issue? (given that we dont want to know what OSGi is and we work with pure java no frameworks etc...)**

My searches end up pointing some frameworks or some web container specific solutions, yet this is quite a simple task that is solved with one class, I'd like to find out if i'm missing something before i start implementing it.

Update (digging deeper) : suppose there is a class loaded by bootstrap which has static state that can be shared between instances (and we really badly want to make sure instances are completely isolated), now that class is obviously not included in our classpath, but it is loaded, and if we copy it instead of reffering it we will achieve the required isolation.

**So do we have the notion of copying or cloneing a class from one classloader to other?**

Comment: Have you tried searching?  For example, using grepcode you can identify classes that extend a given class across multiple libraries.

Comment: I've checked all the classloaders available in jdk8 that extend ClassLoader parent class, but none seems to do what i describe here... Which is expected as this is quite a exceptional case. (i dont expect jdk guys to do all the work for us :)

Comment: Maybe you want a classloader with the extension class loader as the parent.

Comment: Did you try grepcode?  1) Google for "java.lang.classloader source".  2) Click on the grepcode result.  3) In the grepcode page look for the down-arrow symbol to the left of the classname in the sourcecode. 4) Select "Derived Types" from the hover menu. 5) Page through the JDK versions for more "hits".

Comment: I'd attempt to arrange it such that Log4j isn't loaded by the application class loader. Load the implementation of your application through a class loader that is a child of the application class loader and a peer to that of the plugins.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline if you load log4j in any parent then the child can disable log for others simply putting rootlogger off... the point is to isolate them, childs shall not have possibility like that...

Comment: @StephenC thank you very much, i've done type hierarchy using IDE features, but this is much more productive... I'll try to find an existing implementation, and will post updates here.

Comment: @vach Exactly. The fun of global state. So, as I suggested, only put dodgy libraries with mutable statics in leaf class loaders. It may be worth pointing out that if you are using a class loader that does not delegate to its parent first (as recommended for Java EE class loaders), then classes loaded by the parent are still always going to refer to their copy of "overriden" classes.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline regarding your suggestion, its not always the case imagine the host application not using logging? besides thats really not a solution but a hack... bot host and plugin apps shall be able to load anything and on different versions if necessary... Suppose i have class X in jdk (loaded by bootstrap) and it has a global state, how can i clone it (reload it) from parent? Note i dont want to refer to same Class instance, i want to reload it... is it possible? or i have to include the jar to instance class loaders path?

Comment: Ideally i'm looking for a classloader that has 3 ways of loading class, 1. default, 2. noDelegation (fails if it cant find class on its own) and at last 3. Reloads class from parent (creates another instance of that Class with its own global state... does not clone its current instance)

Comment: @vach Any attempt to deal with global state is going to be a hack. Boot classes have a whole host of hacks to deal with global state. "The Java 2 Security Model" for one. I think it's very much less of a hack to have classes that are expecting to have different state to be in peer class loaders, than to hack the class loading mechanism. / There's no need to "clone" a class. Just load the bytes afresh from the same source. You may be able to load ".class" as a class loader resource, though that is subject to break at any time.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll be returning to this question some time later, you'r suggestion is an option, but frankly i think having such a class loader is the clean way to do the task.